# Could service wire going into the meter be copper or aluminum?

Tags: electrical

Does the service wire going to meter coming from the electric company have to be copper or it could be aluminum?
I'm a homeowner and will like to know because I don't want to be screwed by any electrician telling me something different.

Comment: Your electric company has the final say and the electrician does what they say.  Most times it will be aluminum wire since that is cheaper and usually preferred choice.

Comment: So how will the wire in the street make a difference to the amount of electricity you use in your property ? especially as the meter tends to be in or on the house?

Answer (score 2):

The wires from the power company to your weatherhead will, in most cases, will be aluminum and is determined by the power company. They have their own sizing charts for what size they run. The wires from the weatherhead to the meter are the customer's problem and will be determined by the person doing the work or drawing up the plans and will be dictated by electrical codes. They can be copper or aluminum. For underground services, the power company usually runs aluminum from their source to the meter. In both cases, the customer runs the wires from the meter to the main panel or possibly to a disconect first. As before, those wires can be aluminum or copper.